# Executing 'If' statements in PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am new to using phpmyadmin. So far, i am used to creating basic raw queries in MySql. I have this simple query that i'm trying to execute via phpmyadmin's GUI :

(all column names starting with lowercase letters are parameters defined in the GUI)

```
if((Select COUNT(*) from Reviews where ReviewID=reviewID AND UserID=userID) > 0) 
 THEN
  Insert Into reviews(ReviewID, UserID, OrganizationID, ReviewText, ReviewMediaURLs, ReviewRating) 
  Values(reviewID, userID, organizationID, reviewText, reviewMediaURLs, reviewRating) ON DUPLICATE 
  KEY UPDATE ReviewText=reviewText, ReviewMediaURLs=reviewMediaUrls, ReviewRating=reviewRating
END IF
```

It throws an error saying that `The following query has failed to execute`. Now, i'm both new to MySql and phpmyadmin so it's hard for me to determine if it's the way phpmyadmin handles queries or if my query is actually wrong.

If someone can point out the mistake, would be highly appreciated.

**EDIT**

The statement that executes properly so far, is :

```
Insert Into reviews(ReviewID, UserID, OrganizationID, ReviewText, 
 ReviewMediaURLs, ReviewRating) Values(reviewID, userID, organizationID, 
 reviewText, reviewMediaURLs, reviewRating) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ReviewID=reviewID, ReviewText=reviewText, ReviewMediaURLs=reviewMediaUrls, ReviewRating=reviewRating
```

Answer (score 1):

Such IF THEN construct, only works in stored procedure and functions.

For a normal query:

```
SELECT IF(EXISTS(Select 1 from Reviews where ReviewID=reviewID AND UserID=userID)
, @sql:=' Insert Into reviews(ReviewID, UserID, OrganizationID, ReviewText, ReviewMediaURLs, ReviewRating) 
  Values(reviewID, userID, organizationID, reviewText, reviewMediaURLs, reviewRating) ON DUPLICATE 
  KEY UPDATE ReviewText=reviewText, ReviewMediaURLs=reviewMediaUrls, ReviewRating=reviewRating',@sql:='SELECT 1=1');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The SELECT determines which @sql is SET.

And the rest is a [EXECUTE a statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html)

Comment: It's not executing in phpmyadmin and throws the same error. (Sorry, even i feel like a beginner asking such questions!)

Comment: Then check your insert statement. I linked to the prepared statement, so that you can replace the variables.reviewID with user defined variables . and add them in the EXECUTE part

Comment: I rechecked all the parameters again. The query executes without the `IF` block, but doesn't work with it. Check my edited question to see the working part.

Comment: This is the error : `MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt' at line 3`

Comment: this runs in  anormal query without error, even when i put it into a stored procedure or function.